# Spyware for feature phones

Tags: phone, spyware

There are a lot of spywares for android and ios smartphones. Are there spywares for feature phones ? I am using [this](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/essential-phone/GT-E1200ZKTINU) samsung phone, which is basic. I am wondering if somebody who has access to this phone for few hours can bug it.

Comment: why this negative vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a way to put new programs onto the device, malware can be installed.

Using a device with an uncommon operating system might protect you from opportunistic malware which attempts to randomly infect as many devices as possible. When the attacker doesn't care about who they infect, just that they get as many infections as possible, they will target popular platforms like Android, iOS or Windows Phone.

But you specifically mentioned a targeted attack on you and your device in particular. When someone wants to put a bug on you specifically, they could just create a tailored malware specifically for you and your device. Creating a malware is not really that difficult. An experienced programmer can create a simple spyware with basic features in an afternoon.

But the problem is getting it onto the device. When the device you use offers no support at all for installing 3rd party software, an attacker will have a hard time to put their malware onto it. In that case you would only have to worry about code injection through security vulnerabilities in the software already present on the device and hardware-based attacks (e.g. opening the device and meddling with the electronics).

As a general rule of thumb, less complex devices make it harder to find software vulnerabilities (less software = less room for bugs) but easier to find ways to attack the hardware.

Comment: So basically you are saying it is difficult to bug the device i use...right ? one more thing i wanted to ask. my device allows communication using call and sms only, there is no bluetooth, gprs, 3g , wifi etc. Is it possible for the malware to send data , say sending call recording real time to a toll free number?

Comment: @tryingtolearn When the malware has full control over the device, it might be possible for them to make calls without you noticing. It could also dial a different number than you entered without showing it. The system behind that number could then immediately redirect you to the actual number you wanted to call while recording the whole conversation. But that's all just theoretical.

Comment: that was interesting insight. when you say it is all theoretical , you mean such an attack has not been observed or there is no proof of concept available ... right ?

Comment: @tryingtolearn Not to my knowledge, but this is not really my area of expertise. Maybe someone else can give some more insight into this matter.